# How to add an explicit pip dependency on Conda

Tags: python, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I am getting a long list of messages shown below on the log whenever I try to run a python script on the azure.
Please tell me what is causing this and what could be the solution to it.

> Warning: you have pip-installed dependencies in your environment file,
> but you do not list pip itself as one of your conda dependencies.
> Conda may not use the correct pip to install your packages, and they
> may end up in the wrong place.  Please add an explicit pip dependency.
> I'm adding one for you, but still nagging you.

Answer (score 0):

I use conda but had to install some packages from pip, so I
get the same message, even if my .yml file includes the dependency by having  "pip:" explicitly written after the end of the conda installed package list).
This could be a bug (https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/1576).

In my case, I just added "- pip" in the line above "- pip:" (note, without dash nor ":". So now there are two, in this order:
"- pip" and -  below it - "- pip:") and the message disappeared.
This solution was taken from
https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/54e4a91d0da4d659a67e3097040764d3a2f6aa16/tests/conda_env/support/advanced-pip/environment.yml
(which contains an advanced management of pip dependencies)